# How can I sort a two dimensional array's columns?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort two-dimensional array columns. I want to take the dimensions and elements of the array from the user and display it as a matrix. Then subtract the sorted form of the same array. We just need to sort the columns of the array. Please help.

Something like this:

```
{ {0, 1, 3},
  {6, 0, 8},
  {5, 9, 2} }


{ {0, 0, 2},
  {5, 1, 3},
  {6, 9, 8} }
```

I wrote code in C++ for this, I can just sort the first column of the array and display it, but I can't do the other columns. I appeal to you for this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int column, row;
    cout << "Column = ";
    cin >> column;
    cout << "Row = ";
    cin >> row;
    int array[column][row];
    int sortedarray[column];
    for (int z = 0; z < column; z++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < row; a++) {
            cin >> array[z][a];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
        sortedarray[i] = array[i][0];
    }

    cout << "\n";
    for (int y = 0; y < column; y++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            cout << array[y][i] << "    ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n";

    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < column; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < column - i; j++) {
            if (sortedarray[j] > sortedarray[j + 1]) {
                temp = sortedarray[j];
                sortedarray[j] = sortedarray[j + 1];
                sortedarray[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    cout << "COUT sorted array \n ";
    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
        cout << sortedarray[i] << "  ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get your example how do you want them to be sorted? `list_name.sort(key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)` this is python code and would sort the multi-dimensional array in descending order on the basis of 2nd column

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

int getDigitCount( int num )
{
    num = abs( num );

    return ( num < 10    ? 1 :
           ( num < 100    ? 2 :
           ( num < 1000    ? 3 :
           ( num < 10'000   ? 4 :
           ( num < 100'000   ? 5 :
           ( num < 1'000'000  ? 6 :
           ( num < 10'000'000  ? 7 :
           ( num < 100'000'000  ? 8 :
           ( num < 1'000'000'000 ? 9 :
                                    10 )))))))));
}

void printMatrix( const std::vector<int>& array,
                  const std::tuple< const size_t, const size_t >& dimensions, const int maxDigitCount )
{
    const auto& [ rowCount, colCount ] { dimensions };

    std::cout << '\n' << "    \\ Column  ";

    for ( size_t colNumber = 0; colNumber < colCount; ++colNumber )
    {
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw( maxDigitCount + 2 ) << std::setfill(' ') << colNumber;
    }

    std::cout << '\n' << "Row  \\" << '\n' << '\n';

    for ( size_t idx = 0; idx < rowCount * colCount; ++idx )
    {
        if ( ( idx ) % ( colCount ) == 0 )
        {
            std::cout << " " << ( idx ) / ( colCount ) << "            ";
        }

        std::cout << std::left << std::setw( maxDigitCount + 2 ) << std::setfill(' ') << array[ idx ];

        if ( ( idx + 1 ) % ( colCount ) == 0 )
        {
            std::cout << '\n' << '\n';
        }
    }
}

// get row count and column count from the user
auto getDimensions( )
{
    constexpr int MIN_ALLOWED_ROW_COUNT { 1 };
    constexpr int MIN_ALLOWED_COL_COUNT { 1 };
    constexpr int MAX_ALLOWED_ROW_COUNT { 50 };
    constexpr int MAX_ALLOWED_COL_COUNT { 50 };

    int inputRowCount { };
    int inputColCount { };

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter row count: ";
        std::cin >> inputRowCount;

        std::cout << "Enter column count: ";
        std::cin >> inputColCount;

    } while ( inputRowCount < MIN_ALLOWED_ROW_COUNT || inputColCount < MIN_ALLOWED_COL_COUNT ||
              inputRowCount > MAX_ALLOWED_ROW_COUNT || inputColCount > MAX_ALLOWED_COL_COUNT );

    return std::make_tuple<int, int>( std::move( inputRowCount ), std::move( inputColCount ) );
}

// get user input ( user's matrix ) and populate the array
void getArrayElements( std::vector<int>& array, int& maxDigitCount )
{
    for ( std::vector<int>::iterator it = array.begin( ); it != array.end( ); ++it )
    {
        std::cin >> *it;

        if ( getDigitCount( *it ) > maxDigitCount )
        {
            maxDigitCount = getDigitCount( *it );
        }
    }
}

// bubble sort the array
void bubbleSortArray( std::vector<int>& array, const size_t& elementCount )
{
    for ( size_t iterCount = 0; iterCount < elementCount - 1; ++iterCount )
    {
        for ( size_t idx = 0; idx < ( elementCount - 1 - iterCount  ); ++idx )
        {
            if ( array[ idx ] > array[ idx + 1 ] )
            {
                int temp = array[ idx ];
                array[ idx ] = array[ idx + 1 ];
                array[ idx + 1 ] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

// transpose 1D array and store in 1D transposedArray
void transposeMatrix( std::vector<int>& array, std::vector<int>& transposedArray,
                      const std::tuple< const size_t, const size_t >& dimensions )
{
    size_t row { };
    size_t col { };

    const auto& [ rowCount, colCount ] { dimensions };

    for ( size_t idx = 0; idx < rowCount * colCount; ++idx )
    {
        if ( col == colCount )
        {
            ++row;
            col = 0;
        }

        size_t newIdx { row + ( col * rowCount ) };

        transposedArray[ newIdx ] = array[ idx ];

        ++col;
    }
}

void launch( )
{
    const auto [ inputRowCount, inputColCount ] = getDimensions( );

    const size_t rowCount { static_cast<unsigned int>( inputRowCount ) };
    const size_t colCount { static_cast<unsigned int>( inputColCount ) };
    const std::tuple< const size_t, const size_t > dimensions( std::move( rowCount ),
                                                               std::move( colCount ) );
    const size_t elementCount { rowCount * colCount };

    std::vector<int> array( elementCount ); // the 1D array for storing the user's matrix

    int maxDigitCount { };
    getArrayElements( array, maxDigitCount );

    std::cout << "\nOriginal 2D array:\n"; // print out the array

    printMatrix( array, dimensions, maxDigitCount );

    bubbleSortArray( array, elementCount );

    std::cout << "\nSorted 2D array:\n"; // print out the sorted array

    printMatrix( array, dimensions, maxDigitCount );

    std::vector<int> transposedArray( elementCount );

    transposeMatrix( array, transposedArray, dimensions );

    std::cout << "\nTransposed sorted 2D array:\n"; // print out the transposed sorted array

    printMatrix( transposedArray, std::make_tuple< const size_t, const size_t >
               ( std::move( colCount ), std::move( rowCount ) ), maxDigitCount );
}

int main()
{
    launch( );

    return 0;
}
```

And a sample input/output:

```
Enter row count: 5
Enter column count: 4
1  6  11  16
2  7  12  17
3  8  13  18
4  9  14  19
5  10 15  20

Original 2D array:

    \ Column  0   1   2   3
Row  \

 0            1   6   11  16

 1            2   7   12  17

 2            3   8   13  18

 3            4   9   14  19

 4            5   10  15  20


Sorted 2D array:

    \ Column  0   1   2   3
Row  \

 0            1   2   3   4

 1            5   6   7   8

 2            9   10  11  12

 3            13  14  15  16

 4            17  18  19  20


Transposed sorted 2D array:

    \ Column  0   1   2   3   4
Row  \

 0            1   5   9   13  17

 1            2   6   10  14  18

 2            3   7   11  15  19

 3            4   8   12  16  20
```

**Transposed sorted 2D array** is what you want to get as the output (based on my understanding of your question).

Also, there is a function at the top, `getDigitCount` for calculating the maximum number of digits a number has in between all user-provided numbers for string formatting purposes (using `std::setw`).

Answer (score -3):

From what I understand, you want something as below:

1 5 6

2 8 4

9 7 3

to be sorted into:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

The simplest way would be you have to map the 2-D array into a 1-D array - “1 5 6 2 8 4 9 7 3”, and sort them using the most optimal algorithm which would return “ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 “, and then map it back to a 2-D array from a 1-D array.

In effect you could achieve any sort of order, it just depends on your mapping.

You could even achieve something like this:

1 4 7

2 5 8

3 6 9

What you need is the mapping from 2-D to 1-D.

Comment: yes I want to do as you last showed. 1 4 7

2 5 8

3 6 9                                                                                                                                             I wanted to do as you say, but I couldn't. I can't move a two-dimensional array to a one-dimensional array. To switch from a two-dimensional array to a one-dimensional array, two nested for loops were needed. I do this but I can write one of the elements of this for (int i) where can I write the second (int j)? Please help.

Comment: I want as 1 4 7

2 5 8

3 6 9   . which mapping should I use? @Furqan